Wordpress multisite with different sites for every language. How can I set the site based on the users browser location or language?
I have a wordpress multisite with Elementor Pro and different sites for every language
(name.com and name.com/es) How can I set the site based on the users browser location or language? (Without any payed plugin, just free or coding)
